# Advice on storing scraped data with changing fields

Tags: ruby, json, sqlite, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website to build a dataset on product features, where each row is a product and each column is a feature. My scraper returns the following JSON data:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "001",
    "price": "$12",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "id": "002",
    "price": "$13",
    "color": "red"
  }]
}
```

In the past, I have been able to store these type of data in CSV easily as follows (hash=the JSON data above):

```
CSV.open("data.csv","w") do |c|
    c << hash["data"][0].keys
end
hash["data"].each do |d|
    CSV.open("data.csv","a+") do |c|
        c << d.values
    end
end
```

But the fields in the JSON data are not constant:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "001",
    "price": "$12",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "id": "002",
    "price": "$13",
    "discount": "0.05",
    "color": "red"
  }]
}
```

My CSV code no longer works for these data. `discount` appears in the `color` field and the actual `color` field shifts by one column to the right.

What is the best way to store an array of hashes? More generally, what are the trade-offs of CSV vs. SQL-based vs. Document-based?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to using a CSV file.

I would use MongoDB, and specifically Mongoid. Or you can use Postgres and a JSON field. Here's how you can do it with Mongoid:

```
scraping = {
  "data": [{
    "id": "001",
    "price": "$12",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "id": "002",
    "price": "$13",
    "color": "red"
  }]
}

Item.create( data:scraping )
```

item.rb:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :data, type:Hash
```

The data will be serialized as BSON, so valid JSON of any depth will work.

However, be sure to read [legal key names for mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions).

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#hash-fields)

Comment: Thanks. I think 'field data' should be 'field :data'. I tried running this, but it produced the following error: "Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute:
message:
  Attempted to set a value for 'data' which is not allowed on the model Item."

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It should be `:data`. I tested it with Mongoid 5.0.1 and it worked.

Comment: I'm using Mongoid 5.0.1 as well. I forgot to mention that I was getting a different error message at first, which I attempted to fix by supplying a default value as {}. Here was the original error message: Mongoid::Errors::NoClientConfig:
message:
  No configuration could be found for a client named 'default'.
summary:
  When attempting to create the new client, Mongoid could not find a client configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
resolution:

Comment: You need a `mongoid.yml`. Check https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#configuration

Comment: Thank. I made a mongoid.yml file and linked it via `load!' but it isn't working. I'll spend more time trying to figure it out. What would the Postgres example look like? Can you point me to/create a simple example similar to the Mongoid one?

Comment: Here's a good post: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-persist-hashes-in-rails-applications-with-postgresql/. Using a JSON field is pretty straightforward. The only issue is you will probably need a GIN index.